# Getting error code 1 while executing a command on remote machine in C#

Tags: c#, psexec

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string executionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);      
    string remoteToolFileName = executionDir + "\\PSTools\\PsExec.exe";
    string myfolderpath = executionDir;
    string CommandToExecute = "\\\\" + MyHostIP + " -u username -p password ipconfig /all >> \"" + myfolderpath + "\\log.txt\"";
    RunCommand(remoteToolFileName, executionDir, CommandToExecute);
}

private static void RunCommand(string filename, string executionDir, string arguments = null)
{       
    var process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.FileName = filename;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments))
    {
        processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    }

    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = executionDir;
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

**Output:**

Command to execute on remote site MyHostIP :

```
\\MyHostIP -u username -p password ipconfig /all >> "C:\My
folder\log.txt"
```

**Command output:**

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to MyHostIP...


Starting PSEXESVC service on MyHostIP...


Connecting with PsExec service on MyHostIP...


Starting ipconfig on MyHostIP...


ipconfig exited on MyHostIP with error code 1.
```

---

Not sure what is the error. Can anyone help me on this please.

***2nd case:***

Command to execute on remote site Myhost :

```
\\Myhost -u Username -p password "C:\Program Files\..\myapp.exe" -xml "C:\my Client\..\input.xml"
```

**Command output:**

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to Myhost...

Starting PSEXESVC service on Myhost...

Connecting with PsExec service on Myhost...

Starting C:\Program Files\..\myapp.exe on Myhost...

C:\Program Files\..\myapp.exe exited on Myhost with error code -1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the redirect `>>` is being interpreted by the `ipconfig` command, you have to use `cmd /c ipconfig` in order to get the redirect to work properly - i.e. the redirect is part of the `cmd` options, not the `ipconfig` options.

Comment: Hi Petesh,
One more query

Comment: Command to execute on remote site Myhost : \\Myhost -u Username -p password "C:\Program Files\..\myapp.exe" -xml "C:\my Client\..\imput.xml" 
Command output: 

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to Myhost...

Starting PSEXESVC service on Myhost...

Connecting with PsExec service on Myhost...

Starting C:\Program Files\..\myapp.exe on Myhost...

C:\Program Files\..\myapp.exe exited on Myhost with error code -1.

______________

Comment: What could be the reason for the above command failure?? Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Petesh,
I am trying to execute an application which is installed on remote machine by passing an xml file an input. I am getting an error code -1. Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: I don't know anything about the second program. It could require access to a GUI session, so you may need to use the `-i` option to `psexec`. it may return the `-1` code when the XML document is not present where you claim. It probably doesn't have write-privileges to `c:\ ` if that's supposed to be an output file but it's all guesswork without knowing anything about the command being run